# Wide table in Microsoft Word 2016

Tags: microsoft-word

I have a wide table in Microsoft Word 2016.

[**Word document with the table**](https://www.dropbox.com/s/v1io7pp3ntpa6br/table_alignment.docx?dl=0)

[image]

I chose the orientation of the page to be Landscape. Still, not all the columns of the table will fit on one page. The column and row names are the same as this table represent correlation between variables.

I thought rotating the table 90 degrees so it will be across several pages but I couldn't.

I will highly appreciate any help in how to show all the contents of the table (even across several pages) while making the table readable.

Comment: The question is not so clear. Are you trying to just visualize the table, or to print it? If you are just visualizing it, you could switch to Web Layout from Views -> View, or change the paper size to larger one from Layout -> Page Setup -> Size.

Comment: @BorislavIvanov
Thanks for your time and help. I'm submitting it to the university as thesis so I need to PRINT IT and I have to stick to the guidelines and not to change the paper size. So I wonder if there is a way for example to split it (across several pages). I have seen videos in which you can split table by rows across several pages. In my case, I think I need to split by column. I will appreciate your suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've done thorough research, and it seems that MS Word just can't split table horizontally. Given that you are not allowed to change the paper size, you have two inconvenient options:

- Manually split the table into smaller tables that each fit on one page. If you are printing on standard A4/Letter paper, you'll have 4 parts or so.
- Create separate section for the table, and choose custom page size for it, e.g. 24 cm x 50 cm will fit the whole table in Landscape layout. Then print the document with scaling. Printers typically has much higher DPI than monitors (300/600 vs 96), to the text may still be readable.

Answer (score 1):

Next solution avoids creating a new sections, which makes it more difficult to change headers, footers, margins, etc. in a consistent manner.

- Insert a Drawing Canvas (Menu, Insert, Illustration, Shapes, New Drawing Canvas at the bottom of the menu).
- Insert a Text Box inside the canvas (Menu, Insert, Illustration, Shapes, Basic Shapes, first element: Text Box).
- Copy the table and the text you want to rotate and paste it inside the textbox, or directly create them inside the Text Box.
- Select and rotate the Text Box.

In the text flow, a Drawing Canvas works like a figure when either is inserted in a paragraph. You can center the paragraph, add space before or after the paragraph, etc.

If the table does not fit the page, you can decrease the font. You can also play with the margins of the cells of the table.

Of course, you could make a table in Excel and copy it in Word as a figure, and rotate it, but the previous solution has a better resolution to file weight ratio.